# group by removing column I'd like to group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take a list of list and then add it to pandas to sum up by one value.

My list of list:

```
[['she', 'walked', 4],
 ['she', 'my', 3],
 ['she', 'dog', 2],
 ['she', 'to', 1],
 ['sniffed', 'I', 5],
 ['sniffed', 'walked', 4],
 ['sniffed', 'my', 3],
 ['sniffed', 'dog', 2],
 ['sniffed', 'to', 1]]
```

I create the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(distanceList, columns = ['word1', 'word2', 'weight'])
```

the result looks weird(it has the extra index column for some reason):

```
    word1   word2   weight
0   I   walked  5
1   I   my  4
2   I   dog 3
3   I   to  2
4   I   the 1
... ... ... ...
1135    I   walked  5
1136    I   my  4
1137    I   dog 3
1138    I   to  2
1139    I   the 1
1140 rows × 3 columns
```

but when I sum it, seems to combine the words.
I used this:

```
df.groupby('weight').sum()

word1   word2
weight      
1   Iwalkedmydogtotheparkandshesniffedgrassthenrol...   thethethethethetotototototototototototototothe...
2   Iwalkedmydogtotheparkandshesniffedgrassthenrol...   totototodogdogdogdogdogdogdogdogdogdogdogdogdo...
3   Iwalkedmydogtotheparkandshesniffedgrassthenrol...   dogdogdogmymymymymymymymymymymymymymymymydogdo...
4   Iwalkedmydogtotheparkandshesniffedgrassthenrol...   mymywalkedwalkedwalkedwalkedwalkedwalkedwalked...
5   Iwalkedmydogtotheparkandshesniffedgrassthenrol...   walkedIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIwalkedIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII...
```

What I want is if I have:

```
dog, cat, 1
dog, cat, 5
dog, rabbit, 1
```

then the result is:

```
dog, cat, 6
dog, rabbit, 1
```

Comment: taking a sum is different than taking a count

Comment: @PaulH sorry I updated my code to show what I was using. I am using sum().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want is as follows.

```
df.groupby('word1')['weight'].sum()
```

The code calculates sum of `weight` according to the `word1`.

Your code calculates sum of `word1` and `word2` according to the `weight`, and sum of strings are concat of strings. That is why the string is concat (e.g, `Iwalkedmydogtotheparkandshesniffedgrassthenrol`)

**Edit**
I am confusing with the example data.
You should try the following code.

```
df.groupby(['word1', 'word2'], as_index = False)['weight'].sum()
```

The result as follows.

```
    word1   word2   weight
0   dog      cat      6
1   dog      rabbit   1
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a list of just word1 and I assume sum of weight.  I want the pair + summed weight

Comment: if I modify your code to this - df.groupby(['word1', 'word2'])['weight'].sum() then it seems to work but word1 only appears once and all the other word2 show up under it. I think it converted it to a series

Comment: Set parameter as_index as False.